# Making a quadrilateral cyclic by an homothety

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral, geometric-transformation

I am wondering if it is possible to map a (convex) quadrilateral to a cyclic quadrilateral by a homothety? Or is the property of being a cyclic quadrilateral preserved by a homothehty?

I would be very happy, if someone can give an example for illustrating his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) is an angle preserving transformation. As a quadrilateral
is cyclic iff opposite angles are supplementary, homothety preserves
the class of cyclic quadrilaterals.